# Mongo::ConnectionFailure when deploying Rails App to EC2 during create_staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-ec2, rubber

I'm trying to deploy my first app to amazon ec2 using Rubber. I've tried several times and each time the process errors out with Mongo::Connection Failure. I've tried several different instance types from several tiers but am still getting the same error. Just not sure how to proceed.

Here is the error log:

```
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:518:in `connect'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] :
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Failed to connect to a master node at production.foo.com:27017
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] (
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] Mongo::ConnectionFailure
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] )
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:656:in `setup'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:101:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:152:in `new'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:152:in `from_uri'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:89:in `master'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config/database.rb:22:in `configure'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config.rb:273:in `configure_databases'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config.rb:94:in `from_hash'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config.rb:109:in `block in load!'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config.rb:108:in `tap'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/config.rb:108:in `load!'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid.rb:147:in `load!'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/graylog2-web-interface-0.9.6p1/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `require'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from ./script/rails:6:in `require'
 ** [out :: production.foo.com] from ./script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    command finished in 66584ms
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\''  bash -l /tmp/bootstrap_graylog_web'" on production.foo.com
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rubber; but is there a mongodb server process that should be running?  'production.foo.com' looks like a bogus server name.

Comment: 'production.foo.com' is basically a bugus server name. It is simply how I set up my localhost to view my webpage. It's not in reality a web address that others can connect to but I can use it on local machine to view my deployed app.. easier than typing my ec2 instance ip. I'm also new to Rubber.. but it seems mongodb is needed at some stage during the bootstrap step to get configure parts on my app automatically on ec2. I'm not using mongodb as my database, but for whatever reason rubber is using it to bootstrap my app to ec2.

Comment: It's clearly trying to connect to a mongodb instance on a host called production.foo.com.  Apparently rubber has a dependency on mongodb?  You might try temporarily configuring to use 'localhost' instead.

Comment: Yeah, it seems rubber has a dependency on mongodb. I'm a bit at a loss on how to configure rubber to use localhost as I am just using the default settings that rubber generates currently. I will look into it - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and in all honesty I just ran 'cap rubber:bootstrap' again and for some reason, that resolved it...